# Dynamodb - Having mulitple rangekey conditions for the same hash key

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

Could i know if there is a provision of having multiple range key conditions for the same hash key.
For example,if the hash key is 'locality'  and rangekey is 'shopNo'. Then could we have the below 
keyconditionset:

```
>HashKeyCondition: locality EQ  'NewYork'  
>RangeKeyCondition1: shopNo BETWEEN  1 to 10  
>RangeKeyCondition2: shopNo BETWEEN  20 to 30
```

When the above was tried, it was considering only one rangeKeyCondition . Is there any way that we can achieve giving two rangekeyconditions for the same hashkey. I am supposing that it could be possible since for a given hashkey, all the rangekeys under this partition are indexed via a 'sortedindex'.

I can see this can be achieved using a 'QueryFilter' with 'OR' ConditionalOperator but the filter is applied after the key-based retrieval and before the results are returned to you. This may not be efficient, as getting all shopNo's for a locallity and then performing a filter could be slower than getting the only items which satisfy the provided multiple rangekey conditions

Could anyone advice on how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach here is to make multiple Query API calls to DynamoDB in parallel with a subset of the results in each request.

For example:

Request 1: HashKeyCondition: locality EQ  'NewYork' AND RangeKeyCondition1: shopNo BETWEEN  1 to 10

Request 2: HashKeyCondition: locality EQ  'NewYork' AND RangeKeyCondition2: shopNo BETWEEN  20 to 30

In the Java SDK there is a AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient that provides the API call queryAsync: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.html#queryAsync%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.QueryRequest%29

Comment: In the current usecase, there are upto 8 ranges to be checked for the same hash key, that would mean 8 parallel requests. DynamoDBAsyncClient just runs the query request in a separate Execution Context(thread) but the thread is still being blocked. So making parallel requests isn't a scalable solution for this usecase :).

Comment: One question though: If there exists a set of 100 rangekeyitems  for each hashkey,  making a 'queryrequest' for all the records for a particular hashkey and then applying an 'OR conditional query filter' on the rangekey would give the solution in a single request to Dynamo but  is this decently performant ?. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see why this isn't scalable? You can provide a thread pool, so the requests will be parallelized. Each request has to page through results (since a page can only return up to 1MB), so you are likely able to retrieve the data faster with parallel requests.

Comment: Each thread in Java takes upto 1MB. Depending on the number of range conditions, i would have to make parallel requests, each spawning a blocking thread. In some cases, the range conditions count exceed 10. So for serving one locality request, if it spawns on an average of 15 threads. A concurrent 1000 requests will consume a great deal of memory. I get your advise, 'dynamo-geo' library uses similar fashion of threadexecutorservice. But it would be great to have the provision of giving mutliple rangekey conditions for the same hashkey and if this can be considered for further releases.